# Substring() is not working for me in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I having a problem with a part of my XSLT code, I have done this before (long time ago), but for some reason is not working this time.

See,

I use this as input:

```
<xml>   
        <timestamp>20210324 10:42:50:210</timestamp>    
</xml>
```

I would like to extract just: **03** from

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" xmlns:mx="http://murex.com/xslt/common" xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math" exclude-result-prefixes="mx exslt math" >

<!--variables-->

<xsl:variable name="timestamp" select="/xml/timestamp"/>


<xsl:variable name="variable" select="substring($timestamp,5,6)"/>


<!--template-->

<xsl:template match="/">

<example>
    
            <tag><xsl:value-of select="$variable"/></tag>
            
</example>


</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

[image: output]

It doesn't make any sense,
the XPath function:

> string substring (string, number, number?)
> Example:
> substring("12345",2,3) returns "234".

I'm using to debug and run the formula a VBA (from Excel) maybe is that?

Comment: *"It doesn't make any sense"* - it does. `substring()` takes a start position and a character count, not a start position and an end position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the trouble to read the spec. The third argument of substring() is the length of the substring required, not the end position.

A common mistake: if you use lots of languages, you'll know that they all have a `substring()` function and it's always different from the last language you used.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be

<xsl:variable name="variable" select="substring($timestamp,5,2)"/>